# Passing value in factory pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I am learning factory design pattern. I am not able to figure out how we can pass parameters to object created using Factory pattern.

One Small Silly Example:

Suppose I have three class, `Class A` and `class B` and Class `Number`. `Number` being the `base class`. Also, class A expects three integers and has functionality to add them and class B expects two integer and adds them

Code Snippet:

```
int main()
{

    Factory *facObj = new Factory();
    // Addition for Two Integers
    Number * numberObjOne = facObj->createObj("AddThreeInteger");
    Number * numberObjTwo = facObj->createObj("AddTwoInteger");
}
```

Factory.cpp

```
Number * Factory::createObj(string str)
{
    if (str == "AddThreeInteger")
    {
        return new A(1,2,3);
    }
    else if (str == "AddTwoInteger")
    {
        return new B(1,2);
    }
    else            
        return NULL;
}
```

Question: Now no matter what I do I can only add the hard coded numbers. How do I pass these integers value from my Client code or from main(). Its a silly example and I am new to programming. Kindly help me here. How can I not hardcode the value and get the results. Can I somwhow pass the values at `facObj->createObj` Am I making sense? Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete, runnable example. c++11 or better.

Note the use of unique_ptr. Don't use raw pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
#include <utility>

template<class T, class...Args>
struct creatable_from {
    template<class X, class...Ys>
    static auto test(int) -> decltype(X(std::declval<Ys>()...), void(), std::true_type());

    template<class X, class...Ys>
    static auto test(...) -> decltype(std::false_type());

    static constexpr auto value = decltype(test<T, Args...>(0))::value;

};

struct Operation {
    virtual ~Operation() = default;

    virtual int operator()() const = 0;
};

struct Add : Operation
{
    Add(int x, int y)
    : x(x), y(y)
    {}

    int operator()() const override {
        return x + y;
    }

    int x, y;
};

struct Sub : Operation
{
    Sub(int x, int y)
    : x(x), y(y)
    {}

    int operator()() const override {
        return x - y;
    }

    int x, y;
};

struct AddSub : Operation
{
    AddSub(int x, int y, int z)
    : x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {}

    int operator()() const override {
        return x + y - z;
    }

    int x, y, z;
};

struct Factory
{
    template<class...Args>
    std::unique_ptr<Operation> create(const std::string& type, Args&&...args)
    {
        if (type == "Add") {
            return do_create<Add>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        if (type == "Sub") {
            return do_create<Sub>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        if (type == "AddSub") {
            return do_create<AddSub>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        // default - return a null pointer, but would probably be better to
        // throw a logic_error
        return {};
    }

private:
    template<class T, class...Args>
    static auto do_create(Args&&...args)
    -> std::enable_if_t< creatable_from<T, Args...>::value, std::unique_ptr<T> >
    {
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template<class T, class...Args>
    static auto do_create(Args&&...args)
    -> std::enable_if_t< not creatable_from<T, Args...>::value, std::unique_ptr<T> >
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("wrong number of arguments");
    }

};

int main()
{

    auto facObj = Factory();
    auto t1 = facObj.create("Add", 2, 3);
    auto t2 = facObj.create("Sub", 3, 2);
    auto t3 = facObj.create("AddSub", 2, 3, 4);

    std::cout << (*t1)() << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*t2)() << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*t3)() << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
5
1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on design patterns. So I am not sure if the following suggestions are still compatible with the factory pattern.

One way could be to create different methods like `CreateObjectA(int a, int b, int c)` and `CreateObjectB(int a, int b)`. Another option could be to add a `std::vector<int>` to your method `createObj`. If all classes A, B, ... differ in the number of integers, the length of the vector could be used to decide which object to create. If this is not possible you could e.g. use some sort of ID to tell the factory which object to create.

Comment: How do I pass value to these ```CreateObjectA``` from main().

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it.

One way is to have separate create methods in your factory, to construct each one of your subclasses. Each create method would take the appropriate parameters for the subclass it constructs, and forwards them to the subclass's constructor, accordingly.

Another way is to have a separate "parameters" class that would define, in some way, the parameters for the created object. It would allow those parameters to be specified. For this case, a `std::vector` would be appopriate. Then, your create() method would have to validate that the passed parameters are valid, and throw an exception otherwise, or something along the same lines.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you kindly provide one small code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

You could generalize your factory class using templates.

For instance, you could send the type you want to construct to the factory.

This is an example for what could be possible solution for your case:

```
struct Factory {
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    T create(Args&&... args) {
        return T{1, 2, std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }
};
```

It will be used like this:

```
Factory factory;

auto myA = factory.create<A>(1, 2, "an additional char* parameter");

// no additional parameter works too
auto myB = factory.create<B>();
```

Well, this class is pretty simple. It construct a type `T` with the arguments `Args`, plus two int parameter. But it will not allow making a different type depending on the value of a string though.

Btw you should replace every `new` in your code by `std::make_unique`, there where a lot of memory leaks in your code. Alternatively, you can create objects of the stack.

---

### Option 2

If you know what type to construct depending on the parameters you send, you could just overload your function.

Here's what it would look like:

```
struct Factory {
    A create(int a, int b, int c) {
        return A{a, b, c};
    }

    B create(int a, int b) {
        return B{a, b};
    }
};
```

You could use it like this:

```
Factory factory;

auto myA = factory.create(1, 2, 3);
auto myB = factory.create(1, 2);
```

This might be easier to implement. But take note that you will not be able to have a class with two constructor neither you won't be able to have two class with the same parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much!